# I am making a user info command for my Discord bot, and wondering if there is a way to make .createdAt look nicer

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a user info command for my bot, and am using message.author.createdAt to show the time at which the account was created. 
[image: Created At Time]

Right now, it outputs this. It's long and looks ugly, and I'd prefer to just have it say Thursday, 10 May, 2018, getting rid of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
const date = message.author.createdAt;
const newDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
```

This will display you the following for example: **4.4.2019**

---

You could even use a package like `momentJS` where you have the **possibility to show the date in various formats**.

Here you can find more information: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I’ve used this, and it works great. The only problem is that I have 2 embeds. One is sent when the message author doesn’t mention someone, and the other is sent on the user the author mentions. I’ve defined the mentioned user as memberInfo, and I’ve tried modifying your code to fit it, but it just outputs `undefined`. Any leads?

Comment: I think I know what you mean but in my opinion you should create a new question for this because that‘s another problem which hasn‘t something to do with this problem in this question @brickman